# Shiny conditionalPanel Referencing selectInput() multiple = TRUE

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to conditionally display filters in my `sidebarPanel()` if they are selected in an `inputSelect()` where `multiple = TRUE`.

Using the example below, the Shiny App should start with neither the "lob_choice" or "segment_choice" filters being displayed in the sidebarPanel, and I have the following requirements:

1. When both "lob_choice" and "segment_choice" filters are selected in the "filter_choice" filter, both should be displayed.
2. The "lob_choice" and "segment_choice" filters should only be displayed if they are selected in the "filter_choice" filter.
3. When either are de-selected, they should be removed from the sidebarPanel display.
4. It should not matter what order they are selected in in the "filter_choice" filter.

The code below will display one of the conditional panels if it is selected in the "filter_choice" filter, but it won't display either if both are selected at the same time.

#### ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("Parameters"),

      selectInput("filter_choice", 
                  "In which ways would you like to filter the data?", 
                  c("LOB", 
                    "Segment"), 
                  selected = NULL, 
                  multiple = TRUE),

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.filter_choice == 'LOB'",
                       selectInput("lob_choice", 
                                   "Choose Line(s) of Business:", 
                                   c("Brandon", "Kyler", "Trent"), 
                                   selected = NULL, 
                                   multiple = TRUE)),

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.filter_choice == 'Segment'",
                       selectInput("segment_choice", 
                                   "Choose Segment(s):", 
                                   c("LA", "Inverness", "Orlando"), 
                                   selected = NULL, 
                                   multiple = TRUE))),

    mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
  )
)
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({

    data <- data.frame(lob = sample(c("Brandon", "Kyler", "Trent"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                       segment = sample(c("LA", "Inverness", "Orlando"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                       amount = sample(c(100:10000), 1000, replace = TRUE))

    # Filter for LOBs if specific LOBs are selected
    if (length(input$lob_choice) > 0) {
      lob_values <- input$lob_choice
      data <- data %>% filter(lob %in% lob_values)
    }

    # Filter for Segments if specific Segments are selected
    if (length(input$segment_choice) > 0) {
      segment_values <- input$segment_choice
      data <- data %>% filter(segment %in% segment_values)
    }

    data2 <- aggregate(amount ~ lob + segment, data = data, FUN = sum)
    data2[order(-data2$amount), ]

  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()    
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?Conditional Panel`

> condition  A JavaScript expression that will be evaluated repeatedly to determine whether the panel should be displayed

So here we can use JS [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check *filter_choice*

```
condition = "input.filter_choice !== null && input.filter_choice.indexOf('LOB') >= 0"
#and
condition = "input.filter_choice !== null && input.filter_choice.indexOf('Segment') >= 0"
```

Comment: Works great! I had just figured out how to use `input.filter_choice.includes('LOB')`, which would be an alternative to `input.filter_choice.indexOf('LOB') >= 0`, but I was struggling to find the `input.filter_choice !== null` part of your solution. Thanks!